# why does dockerized zap hang at the end of a baseline scan?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, zap

Fresh image and container of 
owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest
The command:

```
docker exec zap1 ./zap-baseline.py
```

Hangs or processes forever afer:

```
FAIL-NEW: 0 FAIL-INPROG: 0  WARN-NEW: 4 WARN-INPROG: 0  INFO: 0 IGNORE: 0   PASS: 12
```

While earlier (2-3 months ago) it executed properly. Btw when I execute the same command inside the container, then it executes and shuts down properly. How to fix this so that jenkins job won't be stuck forever at the summary?

BTW Why does baseline-scan.py always print out the help section if I add '-r report.html' at the end? (EDIT, a typo -t instead of -r, but the problem stays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command doesnt look right to me.

The recommended command is:

> docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com

As per https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan

Its always printing out the help because '-t report-html' isnt valid. Look at the help shown to see the valid arguments. For an html report you should be using '-r report.html'

Comment: Ok so I shouldn't run it on a running container. Is there a way to disable the "fail on warning" feature?

Comment: Yes, use the zap2docker-weekly container - that supports a '-I   do not return failure on warning' option :)

Comment: ok thanks that did work :) btw do you know how to deliver session file to a dockerized zap? Espiecially using the docker run -rm -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com ?

Comment: As per https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan : "If you use 'file' params then you need to mount the directory those file are in or will be generated in" - an example is given on that page